# C++ Pointer value changing to 0x1 unexpectly - how to prevent this

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to debug a problem where the value of a pointer is changing unexpectedly to `0x1` in a member function of a class. I realize that this is probably a common question and due to something changing on the stack. But I'm not experience enough to know exactly what the cause is and what should I change in the design to fix it. Any nice comments or suggestions would be appreciated.

When I try to look up another container (in a different function) whose key is mlir::Operation* , it will fail as the address of the pointer has changed.

I have class called `Schedule`, which looks like this.

The member function `next_schedulable_operation()` looks like this:

```
            std::cout << "The pointer value is " << *op_itr << std::endl;
            candidates_.erase(op_itr);
            std::cout << "The pointer value is " << *op_itr << std::endl;
            schedule_operation(*op_itr);
            std::cout << "The pointer value is " << *op_itr << std::endl;

            schedulable_op_ = *op_itr;  
            std::cout << "The pointer value is " << *op_itr << std::endl;

        }
    }
```

}

The output I get is:

```
The pointer value is 0x555555695650
The pointer value is 0x555555695650
The pointer value is 0x1
```

When I leave out the last cout statement it doesn;t change value but I think this a just a coincidence.

---

Changes after comments:

Comment: After `candidates_.erase(op_itr)`, `op_oitr` becomes invalid (for reasons that should be obvious - the element it used to refer to is no longer in the container, so the iterator has nothing to refer to), and the subsequent `*op_itr` exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: I suspect that you're thinking of `op_itr` as a kind of pointer to a `mlir::Operation*`, which keeps pointing to the same `mlir::Operation*` after it has been erased from the list, but that's not how it works.

Comment: You can sometimes catch suspected memory errors with a combination of compiler warnings, enabling your standard library's debug checks, and compiling with your compiler's address sanitizer or memory sanitizer enabled.

Comment: Thanks. I understand your point about invalidating the iterator after deleting an element from the container. I've modified the code based on the comments and placed it at the end of the original question. Can I create a l local variable mlir::Operation* op and then assign it to the class member variable schedulable_op_?

Answer (score 2):

```
        std::cout << "The pointer value is " << *op_itr << std::endl;
        candidates_.erase(op_itr);
        std::cout << "The pointer value is " << *op_itr << std::endl;
```

after doing these the first two lines, `op_itr` becomes invalid. As soon as you then do `*op_itr` you trigger Undefined Behaviour.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated.

In practice, it means you cannot schedule an operation you already deleted, if I understand your code correctly.

Comment: Hi @Jeffrey thanks. I understand your point about invalidating the iterator after deleting an element from the container. I've modified the code based on the comments and placed it at the end of the original question. Can I create a l local variable `mlir::Operation* op ` and then assign it to the class member variable `schedulable_op_`?